# In vivo, does it take energy to move double bonds from cis to trans long chain unsaturated fatty acids

Tags: bond, biochemistry

In vitro, long chain fatty acids may yield more energy when bonds break, but in vivo, I understood that energy is burned before unsaturated fatty acids can be oxidized because the side groups with double bonds are crowded, and bunched on one side in the cis position, as all unsaturated FA are, and the molecules of oxidation cannot get in between - they cannot access these bonds to oxidize them.

So I thought I read that ATP is used (how much?) to first get those side double bond groups into the trans position so the oxidation enzymes can reach them.  Let me know if this is not true. Or if there is a thread here that really explains this well.

Comment: This question might be a better fit for Biology stackexchange...

Comment: Look up fatty acid cis trans isomerase. They typically do not require energy.